# How to Read div class value

Tags: selenium

In CQ5 Tool web page, user can add a dynamic row which will be generated below. I need  to identify the class value which is consistent for last row and double click on it.

Help much appreciated.

Comment: Problem is you can't find the xpath?

Comment: I want to identify "<div class="x-grid3-row x-grid3-row-alt x-grid3-row-last x-grid3-row-selected" style="width:1089px;"> " Class value and double click on in which i was not able to do.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved with the following way.
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), 'x-grid3-row x-grid3-row-alt x-grid3-row-last') or contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), 'x-grid3-row  x-grid3-row-last x-grid3-row-selected' )]"))).doubleClick().perform();

The problem was i was getting different class names (5 to 6 names)each time i navigate to the page, so i have to use or condition to identify all possible class names and click it.